# User prompted for credentials when using Open id connect authentication through hotstpot, wifi but not in organization domain

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, openid, openid-connect

When I try to log in to my application, it is directed to Azure AD log in screen and I enter my userid, it immediately directs to federated page where it gets the user's domain and logs them in without letting them enter their password. If I run the same application without my organization network domain, it prompts the user everytime for login like open Id single sign on. What should be done to enable that in the domain network?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, if you already configure user sign-in with single sign-on, in the organization domain, the single sign-on will redirect user directly sign-in only with the `userid` with the stored credential in the domain. Outside organization domain, the single sign-on will requires user to enter credentials for verification everytime.

Comment: Yes you are right, I implemented Open Id connect authentication mechanism and as i understand it generates Identity token everytime so I assume it is doing single sign on everytime. It prompts the user to enter Userid but not the password. No matter which user Id I enter in the organization domain, it uses windows domain credentials of the user's computer to automatically log in. Is there any way I can disable that in organization domain?

Comment: If you want to disable SSO, you have two ways: 1. disable by using Azure AD Connect; 2. disable by using PowerShell. For the details, you could read this doc by the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-sso-faq.